# json string over socket

Tags: python, json

I'm new to json usage, I need to send "data" as given,

```
import json, socket

data = '{"command":"off"}'

_send(socket, data)

def _send(socket, data):
   try:
       serialized = json.dumps(data).replace('\\','')
   except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
      raise Exception('You can only send JSON-serializable data')
  # send the length of the serialized data first
  socket.send(('%d\n' % len(serialized)))
  # send the serialized data
  socket.sendall(serialized)#.encode('utf-8'))
```

at the server I need the data as below,

```
{"command":"off"}
```

but the server received the data as below,

```
"{"command":"off"}"20
```

how to remove the additional strings.

Comment: What happens if you remove the single-quotes from `data`, making it a dictionary?

Comment: When I remove single-quotes I get error as  "sendall() argument 1 must be string or buffer, not dict"

Answer (score 0):

Your data is a string, but the server is expecting an object. Try sending it an object instead.

```
data = {"command":"off"} # note this is a python dictionary

def _send(socket, data):
   try:
       serialized = json.dumps(data) # no stripping necessary
   except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
    ...
```

This line was the red flag `json.dumps(data).replace('\\','')` That usually indicates you've accidentially encoded a string when you meant to encode an object.